# Durandal:Move modal pop up to top of page

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, durandal

I am working with durandal and twitter-bootstrap, where I have a page and inside of it i have a modal popup. 
The code for the modal popup is something like:

```
<div id="reportModal" class="messageBox messageBox-fixedSize">
    <div class="modal-header">        
    </div>    
    <div class="modal-body" >          
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer ">
    </div>
</div>
```

the **RESULT** of this in chrome is something like:

```
<div id="reportModal" class="messageBox messageBox-fixedSize ui-draggable" data-view="views/Reports/reportWindow" style="position: relative; margin-top: -151.05555534362793px; margin-left: -395.55555534362793px;" data-active-view="true">
<div class="modal-header">
</div>    
<div class="modal-body">
</div>
<div class="modal-footer ">

</div>
```

The interesting thing on the result it's the style attribute what is  changed for durandal from dialog.js( using compositionComplete method).

```
style="position: relative; margin-top: -151.05555534362793px; margin-left: -395.55555534362793px;"
```

If we go to compositionComplete, the comments about this method are:
"This function is called after the modal is fully composed into the DOM, allowing your implementation to do any final modifications, such as positioning or animation. You can obtain the original dialog object by using `getDialog` on context.model."

My question is how can I add a new position (to the top of the page) based on this method?.

Any help is aprreciated.

Comment: Right click on the element and find the style and look at how it is being computed.  Pretty simple to decipher...

Comment: i have attached a image to the question.

Comment: Click on the computed tab and it will tell you what is taking precedence and assigning that style

Comment: I uploaded a new image, and the strange thing is that I don't see who is the responsible to add these properties. check the second link

Comment: Durandal is responsible for adding these properties. You asked it to. Look at `durandal.css` for the `modalHost` and `messageBox` CSS classes. How are you displaying this popup - with the `app.showMessage()` function or `dialog.show()`? Then you really should have known that the `dialog.js` module in durandal is doing this.

Comment: Thank you @Brett. I am using app.showDialog() and I am able to see that dialog is doing with the position compositionComplete method, the thing what i can't understand is how can I get a new positioning for my modal popup. The comment in durandal says:"* This function is called after the modal is fully composed into the DOM, allowing your implementation to do any final modifications, such as positioning or animation. You can obtain the original dialog object by using `getDialog` on context.model."

Answer (score 2):

Finally I used the compositionComplete

```
public compositionIsCompleted(){
    var styles = {
        'position': 'absolute',
        'margin-top': '-360px',            
        'margin-left':'-250px'
    };

    $("#reportModal").css(styles);
}
```

I hope help to someone else.